# Can PDF preview icons on OS X include page count indicator and other useful things?

Tags: macos, pdf, finder

My download folder tends to contain dozens of papers I intend to read. Unfortunately the all have meaningless names like `922.pdf` or `smith2008.pdf`, and just as uninformative title pages once thumbnailed, so I need to open every one of them just to figure out which is which.

I don't expect miracles, but is there any way OS X could be at least a bit more helpful here? Even something as simple as page count in thumbnail would be quite helpful, and if it managed to extract some metadata or text from title page, that would be just awesome.

As far as I understand, OS X Finder delegates thumbnail generation to whichever program handles particular filetype, so it should be possible to use something else than Preview.app for PDF thumbnails (or PDFs altogether), right?

So is there any OS X option or third party program which does what I want?

Comment: You can also Command+I to get the page count but I think it is cumbersome for what you want.

Comment: Cmd+I doesn't show page count or any other PDF-specific metadata, just generic file information.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention Quick Look. That might be easier thank opening each and every document.

With the doc selected, hit "Space" or the eye-shaped icon in the Finder Icon bar. Arrow keys can be now used to search through your docs quickly.

On another note, I use Hazel from [Noodlesoft](http://noodlesoft.com) to manage my downloads (renaming & sorting). It's a great tool.